# Identify building location comparing coordinates array with longitude and latitude

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-native, expo

In my project, I am attempting to track a person's inner location in large areas that don't have much information via google maps, for schools, etc. Is it possible to compare an array of coordinates, sectioned via google maps like this random building I exported:

```
    151.1943804842342,-33.87137849309211,0 151.1945217121781,-33.87161602555074,0 151.1945003974734,-33.87168274979045,0 151.1940717940047,-33.87184540905557,0 151.1939036387221,-33.8715534499113,0 151.1943804842342,-33.87137849309211,0
```

and compare this to the user's longitude/latitude to tell if they are inside the area? I'm using this expo location boilerplate to identify their current location

https://snack.expo.io/SkqC-nNs-

If this is possible any direction would be greatly appreciated or other methods that would work inside my react-native application. Thanks

Comment: You can use the `containsLocation(...)` function for that, [here is an example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#containsLocation)

Comment: Oh that's just what im looking for thanks!